# How do you find conditions on constants a,b,c so that a system is inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have the these two equations that make up a system:

$x + ay = 1$

$bx+cy =2 $

And I'm supposed to find the constants a,b, and c so that the system is inconsistent. What criteria am I suppose to look for here?

For exactly one solution, I would try to make it so that a row has an nonzero element that matches up with a real number

For infinitely many solutions, I would try to make it so that there's zero across the row.

For no solutions, I would have a row with all zeros that matched with a real number.

But these aren't what I'm trying to find and I am lost on where to go with this problem.

Now I know that for a system to be inconsistent, rk(A) =/= rk (A|b) would I have to use this fact in some way?

EDIT: Attempt with Gaussian Elimination

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cc|c}
        1&a&1\\
        b&c&2\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

R2 = (1/b)R2

R2 = R2-1R1

$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{cc|c}
        1&a&1\\
        0&c/b -a&2/b -1\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$$

At a loss at what to do with 3 variables here.

EDIT: Using  Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's hint:

$ x = 1 - ay $

$ y(c-ab) = 2 -b $

=> $y = \frac{2-b}{c-ab}$

=> $x = 1 - a(\frac{2-b}{c-ab})$

then the solution set is 
$ \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
        x\\
        y\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$ = $ \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
        1 - a(\frac{2-b}{c-ab})\\
        \frac{2-b}{c-ab}\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$

So I see that c-ab cannot be equal to zero.

Therefore: If c-ab = 0 then the system is inconsistent.

Is this a correct conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gaussian elimination can be done more simply:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & a & 1 \\
b & c & 2
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & a & 1 \\
0 & c-ab & 2-b
\end{array}\right]
&& R_2\gets R_2-bR_1
\end{align}
Now the necessary and sufficient condition for the system to be inconsistent is that the third column is dominant (a pivot column). This translates into
$$
c-ab=0 \qquad 2-b\ne0
$$
This is just the same as saying that $\operatorname{rk}(A)\ne\operatorname{rk}(A|b)$.

Note that just $c-ab=0$ does not guarantee inconsistency, because $b=2$ would give a system with infinitely many solutions.

If you're interested in particular values, take $b=1$, $a=1$ and $c=1$.

Comment: When I plug them I do see that row two is 0 0 | 1 which is indeed inconsistent. May I ask how you found the values for a, b, c that is not guess and check?

Comment: @Aephemeral I took $b=1$, so $2-b=1\ne0$; then I need $c-ab=c-a=0$, so $a=c$ and $a=c=1$ is the simplest choice. Also $a=c=0$ is good, with $b$ any number different from $2$. If you want other examples, take $b=42$, $a=2$ and $c=84$.

Comment: Since the question asks me to find all conditions for a,b,c such that the system is inconsistent, is it safe to just say that b =/=2 and c-ab =/= 0?

Comment: @Aephemeral $b\ne2$ and $c-ab=0$.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

with $$x=1-ay$$ we get in the second equation $$y(c-ab)=2-b$$
can you finish?

Comment: I apologize, I'm not sure what you're hinting at here. I've only recently started learning linear-algebra and have gotten up to Gaussian Elimination. Does this have to do something with that?

Comment: but you have got parametrs in your system, i have substitute the $x$ in you second equation

Comment: I updated my work, how does it look?